# S550 Mustangs - route wire from fuse panel to center console?

Tags: electrical, electronics, accessories

Are there any tip and tricks to routing wire from the passenger footwell fuse panel and into the center console? I'm looking to add an accessory that would require a power cord to pop out right below where the three air conditioning vents are on an S550 Mustang dashboard. I know I can use a fuse tap to start the circuit but I'm lost as to how to get from that panel and into the center console. Whats the best way to route the wire? Are there any access points into the center console from the passenger side?

Comment: Zip ties and bailing wire? :o) Really, it shouldn't be an issue. You *can* actually use something like bailing wire to push through from one area to another, then connect the wire you're routing, which you then pull it back through. Can be easier than pulling the dash apart to run it. Just a thought.

Comment: Paulster, make this “an answer”!  Zip ties and wire it is.  You can lower the glove box into the  “service position” and remove the trim around the center vents to possibly gain a little more visibility.  Note that your vehicle has an **airbag in the glove box door** so follow proper precautions.